# Create a new column based on a string of another column

Tags: python, pandas, string, function

I have a column about the Categories of videogames. Each row has a combination of categories depending on the game type. Ex: Single-player, Multi-player, Steam, PvP, Cross-Platform... Each cell can have multiple categories separated by a coma. I want to create a new column based on whether we have 'Single player', 'multi-player' or both in the Category column.

I am stuck with the following function:

```
def categories(df):
    if df[df['Categories'].str.contains('Single-player')]:
        return 'Single-player'
    if df[df['Categories'].str.contains('Multi-player-player')]:
        return 'Multi-Player'
df['New_col'] = df.apply(conditions, axis =1)
```

I do not know how to create the condition where both categories appear

Thanks!

Comment: what value should be returned for both categories condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to get the expected result:

```
def categories(row):
    if 'Single-player' in row['Categories'] and 'Multi-player' in row['Categories']:
        return 'Both'
    elif 'Single-player' in row['Categories']:
        return 'Single-player'
    elif 'Multi-player' in row['Categories']:
        return 'Multi-player'
    else:
        return 'Other'

df['New_col'] = df.apply(categories, axis=1)
```

**Explanation:**

If you need to check multiple conditions, you can use an if statement with multiple conditions. The syntax for this is:

Both conditions must be true: `AND` operator.

```
if condition1 and condition2:
    #execute this code
```

One of the conditions needs to be true: `OR` operator.

```
if condition1 or condition2:
    #execute this code
```

For more information see: [Check multiple conditions in if statement](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-multiple-conditions-in-if-statement-python/)

Comment: This could be simplified somewhat using `df['New_col'] = df['Categories'].map(categories)` to pick up just the Categories string in the function to avoid the repeated access.